# How to skip a particular line from a text file if that line has white space or a particular character in C programming?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, fgetc

I'm new to string and file operations in C and I have a text file file.txt with below data.

I'm reading a text file which contains below information

```
1.#comment
2.Name="Audi"
3.Class="Premium"
4. Cost="High"
5.   #
```

I wanted to store contents of this file into a buffer with below conditions:

1. skip lines containing '#' in it which are for comments
2. skip lines which are starting with white space.

while writing to the buffer.

I have used fgets() to read each line by line  which checks for '#' presence in it

My sample code is below:

```
char buffer[64];
    
    FILE* fp= fopen("file.txt", "r"); 
    if (NULL == fp) {
            printf("file can't be opened \n");
        }
    else
    {
     
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) 
    
    {                                                                                                                                   
        if(buffer[0]=='#')
        {
            continue;
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   printf("%s", buffer); 
     }  
    }
```

This code works fine if first character of line is #(1st line), but I wanted to skip line whenever I get a # in the line not only first one(5th line in text file needs to be skipped). Similarly I wanted to skip line if I have white space in line(4th line). I'm getting stuck here and unable to proceed further. Is there an efficient way to do the same? Please support

Edit: As suggested I tried with isspace & strchr and it is working.Thank you for support.Also one more query is whether isspace and strchr are misra 2012 complaint?

Comment: you need strchr https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html

Comment: I suggest using `strchr` (find a single character) or `strcspn` (find one of a set such as `"# \t\n"`).

Comment: Note that using `strchr` will give a false positive for lines like `Class="Premium#1"` unless you verify nothing prior to its position is anything other than whitespace. And if you have to do that, you may as well fore-scan it in the first place.

Comment: I tried with strchr but buffer had only the line just after  the first occurrence of the character # in the file . Rest of my information was lost.

Comment: @Ellariz Should `"abc # def\n"` get skipped?

Comment: I need to skip lines having #,lines preceeding with whitespace.In above file.txt,I want only line 2,3 present in my buffer and rest needs to be skipped

Answer (score 1):

use `strchr`

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) 

{                                                                                                                                   
    if(strchr(buffer, '#') != NULL)
    {
        continue;
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     printf("%s", buffer); 
 }  
}
```

it returns NULL if char not in string

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a line that contains a `'#'` is retained if it is not the first non-white-space letter:

**To skip if line begins with a white-space**

```
    if(isspace(buffer[0])) continue;
```

**Otherwise to skip if line begins with a #**

```
    if(buffer[0] == '#') continue;
```

**Together**

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) { 
  unsigned char first = buffer[0];
  if(isspace(first) || (first == '#')) continue;
  ...
}
```

Otherwise search for a `'#'` as suggested by [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298914/2410359).